# How to make login keyring forget a password

Tags: keyrings

The "Unlock Login Keyring" popup is useful, but how do I make it forget a password for a specific website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use seahorse to change and delete keyrings and items in keyrings.

Comment: How would that work in this case?

Answer (score 1):

The passphrase is stored in your *login* keyring. You can access that with *seahorse* (*passwords and keys* from the dash)

[image: screenshot]

On the left side select *login*, then browse on the right side to find the entry (the description should be self-explanatory, it contains the name of the resource)

Right-click on the entry, select *delete*.

When you try to access the resource again you get the same dialog as before.