# Where is a passphrase stored when I request "Remember until I logout"?

Tags: password, keyrings

When you (with Nautilus or Nemo) access a resource that requires a passphrase you are presented with a dialogue that gives you the choices to

- forget password immediately
- remember password until you logout
- remember forever

When you select "remember forever" the passphrase is stored in your *login* keyring, accessible with *seahorse* (also see [How to make login keyring forget a password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223592/how-to-make-login-keyring-forget-a-password))

Now when I selected *remember password until you logout* I cannot find that entry in seahorse. Where is it stored?

<sub>Note: I am well aware of the possibility to simply logout/login but I still want to find the place where it is stored.</sub>

Comment: It would make sense if it was just kept in RAM.

Comment: And this depends on the application. You phrase it in a general way, but these particular options are usually seen in Nautilus and Nemo (probably other file managers as well).